# how to label subgroup in ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanna the figure as the attachment. Data is grouped by "Response (NR,R)", but within each group (NR and R), the time points display at x-axis instead of showing NR/R.

My code is:

```
ggplot(data = data_melt, 
       aes(x = Response, y = SPV, fill = Response, labels = TimePoint))+
  geom_boxplot(position =  position_dodge(width = 1), width = 0.4, lwd = 1, alpha = 0.01, show.legend = FALSE)+  
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 4, position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 1), alpha = 0.25, aes(color = Response)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("R" = "#FF6666", "NR" = "#00c000")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.3,0.3), 
                     breaks = c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
                     labels = c(-0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), name = "SPV")+
  stat_compare_means(size = 8, label = "p.format") +
  facet_wrap( ~ Subset, ncol = 4)+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.5),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"),
        panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could facet by the NR/R variable:

```
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df <- expand.grid(c("NR", "R"), paste0("T", 1:5), 1:10)
df$Var3 <- rnorm(nrow(df))

# plotting
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, Var3)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~ Var1, switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: Any other way if I do not want to facet by NR/R variable?